# Can I turn off quartz scheduler with a property setting?

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

We disable the quartz scheduler locally by commenting out the scheduler factory bean in the `jobs.xml` file.

Is there a setting for doing something similar in the `quartz.properties` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use Spring Framework you can make subclass from org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean and override afterPropertiesSet() method.

```
public class MySchedulerFactoryBean extends org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean {

    @Autowired
    private @Value("${enable.quartz.tasks}") boolean enableQuartzTasks;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (enableQuartzTasks) {
            super.afterPropertiesSet();
        } 
    }
}
```

Then change declaration of factory in xml file and set "enable.quartz.tasks" property in properties file. That's all.

Of course, instead using @Autowired you can write and use setter method and add

```
<property name="enableQuartzTasks" value="${enable.quartz.tasks}"/>
```

to MySchedulerFactoryBean declaration in xml.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, is there any annotation missing  fromMySchedulerFactoryBean?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that there is a property `autoStartup` in `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`. So you can configure it in XML config like this:

```xml
<bean id="quartzFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="${cron.enabled}"/>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="someTriggerName"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks to https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/configure-spring-to-turn-quartz-scheduler-onoff

Answer (score 5):

No.  But the properties file doesn't start the scheduler.

The scheduler doesn't start until/unless some code invokes scheduler.start().

Answer (score 4):

You can disable Quartz Scheduler if you use Spring Framework 3.1 for creating and starting it.
On my Spring configuration file I use the new profiles feature of Spring 3.1 in this way:

```xml
<beans profile="production,test">
    <bean name="bookingIndexerJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.xxx.indexer.scheduler.job.BookingIndexerJob" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="timeout" value="10" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="indexerSchedulerTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="bookingIndexerJob" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="1000" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="indexerSchedulerTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="ds_quartz-scheduler"></property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:quartz.properties" />
        <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Only when I want to start the Scheduler (for example on the production environment), I set the `spring.profiles.active` system property, with the list of active profiles:

`-Dspring.profiles.active="production"`

More info here:

- http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-profiles-or-not

Answer (score 2):

I personally like the answer from [Demis Gallisto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10895111/6267583). If you can work with profiles, this would be my recommendation.

Nowadays people most likely prefer to work with Annotations, so as an addition to his answer.

```java
@Configuration
@Profile({ "test", "prod" })
public class SchedulerConfig {
  @Bean
  // ... some beans to setup your scheduler
}
```

This will trigger the scheduler only when the profile `test` OR `prod` is active. So if you set an different profile, e.g. `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` nothing will happen.

If for some reasons you cannot use the profile approach, e.g. overlap of profiles ...

The solution from [miso.belica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39528576/6267583) seems also to work.

Define a property. e.g. in `application.properties`: `dailyRecalculationJob.cron.enabled=false` and use it in your `SchedulerConfig`.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerConfig {
  @Value("${dailyRecalculationJob.cron.enabled}")
  private boolean dailyRecalculationJobCronEnabled;

  @Bean
  public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(JobFactory jobFactory, Trigger trigger) throws 
    SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
    factory.setAutoStartup(dailyRecalculationJobCronEnabled);
    // ...
    return factory;
  }
  // ... the rest of your beans to setup your scheduler
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue: disable scheduler in test scope. 
Here is part of my applicationContext.xml

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
```

And I've disabled scheduler using 'primary' attribute and Mockito. Here is my applicationContext-test.xml

```
<bean id="myScheduler" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock" primary="true">
     <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler"/>
</bean>
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I've found in a spring boot context for tests is to simply:

```java
@MockBean
Scheduler scheduler;
```

Answer (score 0):

This scala code works：

```scala
 @Bean
 def schedulerFactoryBean(): SchedulerFactoryBean = {
   new SchedulerFactoryBean {
     override def afterPropertiesSet(): Unit = {}
   }
 }
```